# How do you monitor http traffic from Google App Engine dev_appserver on OSX?

Tags: macos, http, google-app-engine

I want to find out the exact http requests that my Google App Engine app is making to external websites.  I've tried Charles Proxy, TcpCatcher and Wireshark, but haven't been able to get the traffic between the dev server and the outside world.  I can get the traffic between the browser and the dev server OK, but that is not what I want.  What setup do I need to be able to monitor this?

Comment: It's very strange : Wireshark work very well for that out of the box. Can you give more details like a code sample of your request?

Comment: Oh yeah, with Wireshark my main issue was trying to find the appropriate request. I couldn't find the one that was requesting the page that I was seeing turn up.  I could find the http requests for the the css etc for the page, but not for the page itself.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use charles or whatever for this but you might (and I haven't tried this...) need to specify the proxy to use on the JVM for the dev server. Something like:

```
JAVA_FLAGS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8888
```